# How does GridDB support cluster managers in distributed data management?

Tags: python, distributed-computing, griddb, cluster-manager

I'm working on a project that involves using GridDB for distributed data storage and management. I've been reading the documentation, but I'm still a bit unclear about the specific role of the GridDB Cluster Manager in this context. Can someone provide an example of how the GridDB Cluster Manager functions in managing distributed data within a GridDB cluster?
I'm particularly interested in understanding:

- How the Cluster Manager facilitates data distribution and load balancing.
- Its role is to ensure high availability and fault tolerance.
- Any configuration or best practices related to optimizing the Cluster Manager's performance.
  Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I have read the documentation and few articles.

Comment: The question is too broad. You should ask specific questions. You can find Best Practices anywhere. Focus more on the issue at hand.

Comment: I went through the docs and study material available but didn't get the satisfactory answer to that. Also I want to get advice from someone's personal experience.